# MSBTS_HostSetting is Not Found

Tags: powershell, biztalk, biztalk-2013r2

Upon building a script to automate the deletion of Host and Host Instances, I run the script below in PowerShell.

PS

> `C:\WINDOWS\system32>
>   [System.Management.ManagementObject]$objHostSetting =
>   ([WmiClass]"root/MicrosoftBizTalkServer:MSBTS_HostSetting").Delete()`

However, after running the script, it seems that the MSBTS_HostSetting is gone because I was receiving the error below every time I am running it.

PS

> C:\WINDOWS\system32> 
>   [System.Management.ManagementObject]$objHostSetting
>   =[WmiClass]"root/MicrosoftBizTalkServer:MSBTS_HostSetting" Cannot convert value "root/MicrosoftBizTalkServer:MSBTS_HostSetting" to type
>   "System.Management.ManagementClass". Error: "Not found " At line:1
>   char:2
>   +  [System.Management.ManagementObject]$objHostSetting =[WmiClass]"root/MicrosoftB ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidCastToWMIClass

I am trying to load the BizTalkOMExplorer but the `MSBTS_HostSetting` has not returned. Any suggestions or knowledge how can I bring it back.

Comment: Why do you think the setting would be there after you have deleted it?

Comment: Honestly, I'm not aware that the delete() would delete the entire setting that's why I'm trying to bring it back though there are less topics in the web for this.

Comment: What did you think the `.delete()` method would do? Surely you checked the [documentation for the class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560307.aspx) and the [sample code for manipulating it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560467.aspx) before writing and using your code?

Comment: Nope. Didn't read anything for the delete specific from msbts because if i had then i wouldn't test running it. Btw, didn't post this issue to tell me the obvious that i made a mistake. I posted this to seek help to solve it which i think what this page is all about. But still thank you for answering (even though it didn't help).

Answer (score 0):

Just fixed my issue! Below are what I've done.

1. Open CMD and register the BTSWMIProvider.dll
   Example:
   Regsvr32.exe “C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft BizTalk Server 2013 R2\Bins32\BTSWMIProvider.dll“
2. Run the following in CMD as well.
   mofcomp.exe BTSWMISchema.mof
   mofcomp.exe BTSWMISchema.mfl
3. Restart WMI in services.

This would do the trick! :)

Answer (score 0):

With PowerShell, you can get your HostInstances as:

```
$hostInstances = Get-WmiObject MSBTS_HostInstance -namespace root\MicrosoftBizTalkServer -ErrorAction Stop
```

And then you can find which one you want to delete and invoke Delete method:

```
 $hostInstances[0].Delete()
```

The same with Hosts:

```
$hosts = Get-WmiObject MSBTS_Host -Namespace root\MicrosoftBizTalkServer -ErrorAction Stop
$hostToDelete = $hosts | where {$_.Name -eq 'HostNameToDelete'}
$hostToDelete.Delete()
```